# array and global object

Tags: javascript, arrays, frontend

I Have code like this:

```
var ui = ["one","two","three"];
ui.forEach(function(id) 
{ 
   ui[id] = "msg_all " + id 
});
console.dir(ui);
```

Why ui[0] == "one" when window.one == "msg_all one"

Comment: @gra window is the base scope of all javascript objects, and it's automatically "attached" to each variables you define, unless you use "var" before the declaration, in this case the scope of the variable it's local (that means that it's contained inside the parent function, or is otherwise global too, if you are declaring your variable outside a function block). Moreover window is defined as a constant, that is you can't redefine the window object (you will get an error saying "type error: redeclaration of const window").

Comment: because ui[id] is equal to an example ui["one"] so window.one is equal to that message

Comment: while ui is an array with inde 0 1 2

Comment: Do you know that array indexing starts from zero?

Comment: what do you like to achieve?

Comment: can you tell me why ui["one"] == "msg_all one" and window.one == ui["one"]

Comment: where do you get `window.one` from?

Answer (score 1):

You have wrongly use the forEach function, the first argument for this function is the item for each iteration, and the second argument is the index.

```
var ui = ["one","two","three"];
ui.forEach(function(item, index) 
{ 
   ui[index] = "msg_all " + item 
});
console.dir(ui);
```

Comment: no, this is good example. I know that second argument is index when is first argument item. But why when i run console.dir i gest thos msg:
["one","two","three"]

Comment: ["one","two","three"]
0:"one"
1:"two"
2:"three"
one:"msg_all one"
two:"msg_all two"
three:"msg_all three"
length:3
__proto__:Array[0]

Why?

Comment: `id` is not an integer, why you use it directly as an index in `ui` array?

Comment: so, why ui["one"] == "msg_all one" ?

Comment: var arr = [];
arr["x"] = "y";
console.log(arr.lenght)// 0 :(
but:
console.log(arr["x"])// "y"
Why length is 0 ?

Comment: `array` in js is an object, so if you set `arr["x"] = "y"`, that means you add a new property in the `arr` object, this statement is equal to `arr.x = "y"`. But actually, you didn't change the array itself, you just added an extra property to `arr`, so you can see that `arr.length` is equal to 0, however `arr["x"]` equal to "y"

Comment: Thanks you, my problem is death. Greeting from strange Poland